# Is Amazon Web Hosting Better than Dedicated cPanel Web Hosting for Large traffic WP Sites

Tags: web-hosting

I have a wordpress site and having 50k visits a day
I am currently using a dedicated server but I feel the site is quite slow
and sometimes reach a downtime when traffic spike up.
I am looking to amazon or something similar, just wandering if they are better and cheaper than cPanel

Comment: cPanel is a control panel app that web hosts use. 50k page views is not so significant that a dedicated sever cannot handle it. There has to be a reason such as  being I/O bound which is where most hosts fall apart. I used to be a web host and one of my own sites hosted on a Cobalt server handled 100k page views per hour before slowing down too much. At 100k, pages still completed within 4 seconds. This was with a CMS.

Comment: Also consider that WP is a pig. Find out where your site is failing specifically. Learn how to analyze system performance metrics to see what you really need before jumping into another situation. Otherwise, you could be wasting your time and effort. Cheers!!

Comment: WordPress needs a caching plugin if you want it to be fast.   Have you installed one?   WP Super Cache is a good one.   WP can decently well even on a slow host with some caching.

Comment: I already did that cache plugin, cdn , dedicated server from a known hosting and still having spike issue so I am wondering if amazon hosting scales better than cPanel hosting? oh I already tried server that uses litespeed but not nginx yet

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think its not a duplicate question. I should rephrase my question,

Comment: Both CDNs and Amazon come in a variety of sizes and levels.  Amazon is easier to get a bigger slice for higher cost.